# Como montar essa query

Tags: php, sql

Preciso retornar os novos clientes de um determinado período, porém no banco só consigo trabalhar com "*anocobranca, mescobranca*", para contar como um novo cliente eu verifico todos que contrataram um serviço dentro do período, só que o cliente pode contratar em períodos diferentes e eu não posso contar como um novo se ele já contratou em um período anterior.

exemplo:

```
anocobranca = 2021
mescobranca = 04
```

digamos que o resultado seja apenas **1** o id desse cliente é **9999**
se esse mesmo cliente contratou um serviço em 2017/05 ele não pode ser ser somado como novo no período 2021/04.

Tabela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

dentro de um foreach eu monto a consulta e retorno a quantidade

```
$consulta = "SELECT distinct cs.idclienteunidade from clienteunidadeservico cs
    where cs.anocobranca = $ano and cs.mescobranca = $mes";
```

isso funciona para os novos desse período porém em algum desses retornos pode ter um que é velho e não novo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supondo que seu banco de dados seja o PostgreSql, proponho a consulta SQL abaixo:

```
SELECT distinct cs.idclienteunidade 
  from clienteunidadeservico cs
    where cs.anocobranca = 2021 and cs.mescobranca = 4
    and not exists (select * 
                      from clienteunidadeservico cs2 
                     where cs2.idclienteunidade = cs.idclienteunidade
                       and cast( (cast(cs2.anocobranca as varchar) || '-' || lpad(cast(cs2.mescobranca as varchar),2,'0') || '-' || '01') as date) <
                           cast( (cast(cs.anocobranca as varchar) || '-' || lpad(cast(cs.mescobranca as varchar),2,'0') || '-' || '01') as date)
                   )
```

Algumas considerações:

- Esse exemplo foi feito considerando um banco de dados Postgresql.
- Usada a lógica: Selecione os clientes distintos de um período específico (ano/mes) que não **exista** um registro com período(ano/mês) anterior ao período especificado inicialmente, como `anocobranca = 2021` e `mescobranca = 04`
- Preferi gerar uma data a partir dos campos `anocobranca` e `mescobranca` utilizando as funções `cast` e `lpad` da seguinte forma:

Observe:

```
cast( (cast(cs.anocobranca as varchar) || '-' || lpad(cast(cs.mescobranca as varchar),2,'0') || '-' || '01') as date)
```

Observei que o seu campo `mescobranca` é inteiro, então usei a função `lpad` para preencher com um zero a esquerda caso necessário, visto que desejo gerar as datas conforme seu exemplo 2017-05-01 e 2021-04-01 para assim realizar a comparação entre as duas datas.

Considerando os dados de exemplo abaixo:

| idclienteunidadeservico | anocobranca | mescobranca | idclienteunidade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021 | 4 | 251 |
| 2 | 2021 | 4 | 548 |
| 3 | **2020** | 5 | 251 |
| 4 | 2021 | 5 | 548 |

Ao executar a consulta proposta como solução, o resultado foi:

| idclienteunidade |
| --- |
| 548 |

Da forma demonstrada, acredito que a consulta proposta resolva o problema.

**Observação:**
O PostgreSql até faria o `cast` corretamente sem `lpad`, mas preferi usar para exemplificar como fazer se o sistema de banco de dados exigir os dois caracteres para o mês. A consulta `select cast('2021-4-15' as date)` resulta `2021-04-15`.

Answer (score 1):

Deve ter uma solução com melhor performance (talvez com `JOIN` + `IS NULL`), mas o mais fácil é usar um `NOT IN`:

1. Seleciona aquilo que quer:

   `SELECT ... WHERE cs.anocobranca = $ano and cs.mescobranca = $mes`
2. Exclui aquilo que não quer:

   `NOT IN (... WHERE cs.anocobranca != $ano and cs.mescobranca != $mes)`

No final ficaria como:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   cs.idclienteunidade 
from 
  clienteunidadeservico cs 
where 
      cs.anocobranca = $ano 
  and cs.mescobranca = $mes 
  and idclienteunidade NOT IN (
    select 
      idclienteunidade 
    from 
      clienteunidadeservico 
    where 
      clienteunidadeservico.anocobranca != $ano 
      and cs.mescobranca != $mes
  )
```